# yii\base\ErrorException Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Tags: php, yii2

```
'rowOptions' =>function($dataProvider) use($isAccountingTeamOrAdmin){
        $value = 0.00;
        $results = array($dataProvider);
        $params = isset(\Yii::$app->request->queryParams) ? \Yii::$app->request->queryParams : '';
        if($results){
            $value = Yii::$app->payroll->getPayrollAmountForFloodViewHistory($results, $isAccountingTeamOrAdmin, $params);
        }
        if($value > 0){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    },
```

This line $results = array($dataProvider); how to implement ??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the method getData() from your dataprovider

`$results = $dataProvider->getData();`